# Are there any tools or APIs that would allow retailers to accept XTZ in a commerce flow?

Tags: api

I am developing an online retailer and am looking into if it is possible to accept XTZ as part of a regular ecom sales flow. Is there any equivalent of a Coinbase Commerce like service that can accept XTZ?

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that MoonPay is working on it currently.

Answer (score 0):

Install this plugin in your WooCommerce store, set a receiver address and start collecting crypto payment such with uUSD or any other FA2 compatible Tezos token.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/beacon-payment-gateway/

Answer (score 0):

There is an open-source solution for this flow. [TezPay](https://github.com/tzConnectBerlin/tezpay).

> The purpose of this project is to deliver reliable, robust payment receipts on the Tezos infrastructure while minimizing chain usage and maximizing privacy.